# Error in Union trying to sort null at end in sql server

Tags: sql-server, union

I am trying to sort my database in some particular order, but I want all null's at the end, so I am selecting all values with not null, and then selecting all values WITH null, and trying to join them with Union.. like:

```
SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE preferenceOrder IS NOT NULL 
                               ORDER BY preferenceOrder ASC
UNION

SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE preferenceOrder IS NULL 
                               ORDER BY preferences ASC
```

but the server throws an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

I cant find out what the error is though.. what is wrong with the sentence above?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you should `order by (case when preferenceOrder is null then 0 else 1 end), preferenceOrder` instead of this union.

Comment: oh, gimme a minute, will try it out!

Comment: hm, now it says  

    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: (case when preferenceOrder is null then 0 else 1 **END**)

Comment: yup, END fixed it, but doesnt sort the way i want it to, unless i do this: <b>select * From countries order by (case when preferenceOrder is null then 999999 else preferenceOrder end), preferenceOrder</b> is it better to use this: <b>SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY COALESCE(sortOrder,999999) ASC</b> ? I dint want to use it because of the 999999.. what if my table goes over that number?

Comment: thanks, I just ended up by using the modified version of your querry.

Comment: Something a little shorter is to use the ISNULL operator thus you could just have ISNULL(PreferenceOrder,0) - this is logically equivalent to:
order by (case when preferenceOrder is null then 0 else preferenceOrder end) which I think is what you are after